# ImportError: No module named absl.testing

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I've been trying to run the [Object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md), at the point to test if the instalation worked:

```
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

I got the following error:

```
    File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 18, in <module>
    from absl.testing import parameterized
ImportError: No module named absl.testing
```

I couldn't find a solution anywhere. Already tried `pip install absl-py` and `pip3 install absl-py` but without success.
Hope you could help me.

Comment: How did you install TF? Via pip3 install TF gpu!? And which TF version do you have? Are you sure you every installation you did matches your python version?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Got it working by using `python3 object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py`
instead of `python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py`. I forgot that I was using TF for python3.

Answer (score 3):

- First install absl-py by running command if you are using tensorflow
  with   python3

  *sudo pip3 install absl-py*

  otherwise

  *sudo pip install absl-py*
- After that run

  *python3 object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py*

  Cheers, You done it !!

Comment: shouldn't `pip install` with sudo